# Handling of clip area in lightweight components does not match documentation?

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint

The documentation for [`java.awt.Graphics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) says the following (I added some **emphasis**):

> All rendering operations modify only pixels which lie within the area
>   bounded by the current clip, which is specified by a `Shape` in user
>   space and is controlled by the program using the `Graphics` object. This
>   *user clip* is transformed into device space and combined with the
>   *device clip*, which is defined by the visibility of windows and device
>   extents. The combination of the user clip and device clip defines the
>   *composite clip*, which determines the final clipping region. **The user
>   clip cannot be modified by the rendering system to reflect the
>   resulting composite clip**. The user clip can only be changed through
>   the `setClip` or `clipRect` methods.

Further, the documentation for the [`getClip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getClip--) method says:

> Gets the current clipping area. This method returns the user clip,
>   which is independent of the clipping associated with device bounds and
>   window visibility. **If no clip has previously been set, or if the clip
>   has been cleared using `setClip(null)`, this method returns `null`**.

However, the following sample program prints a non-null clipping area:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class ClipTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.setSize(300,200);

        Component lightweight = new Component() {
                public void paint(Graphics g)
                {
                    System.out.println(g.getClip());
                }
            };
        f.add(lightweight);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Am I overlooking something, or is this a bug in the spec or in the implementation?

**Update:**

- The code above does not use Swing. It uses plain AWT. I tagged the question 'swing' because this *also* happens with Swing, but it is not Swing-specific.
- Furthermore, I am not asking "why" this happens. I have studied the source code and I can see that setClip() is being called internally in some cases. But this does not seem to match what the Javadocs say (see quoted sections above). Hence my question: Is this a bug in the implementation **or** in the spec, or I am just missing something?

Comment: When a component is painted, the clipping rectangle is automatically set to the components bounds.  You have to remember, that `Graphics` is used for more things then just painting components ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I know. As the update says I was not asking why this happened but about the apparent mismatch between what was happening and the Javadocs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the answer seems to be in the documentation for [`java.awt.Component.paint(Graphics)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphics--), which says:

> This method is called when the contents of the component should be
>   painted; such as when the component is first being shown or is damaged
>   and in need of repair. The clip rectangle in the `Graphics` parameter is
>   set to the area which needs to be painted.

This is the bit of information that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Please note that this answer is *not* correct, due to misinterpretation of the actual question (which I cannot answer). I will leave it open for now, maybe someone else will find it useful.</sub>

---

1. The `getGraphics()` method of `Component` [calls `setClip()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Component.java#Component.getGraphics%28%29).
2. As you may already know, normally `paint(Graphics)` only get's called by the [`RepaintManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html), which is responsible for repainting. Several times it calls `setClip()` before `paint()`.

So, to my knowledge: *No*, the documentation isn't wrong. If `RepaintManager` or `Component` wouldn't call `setClip()`, `getClip()` would indeed return `null`. You can view the full source code of `RepaintManager` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/RepaintManager.java).

Comment: @Grodriguez Sorry, I guess I got influenced by the `swing` tag. Does the edit help you? If not, I will delete this answer as I kind of misinterpreted the question.

Comment: As I think this answer should be here. It contains useful information, and somewhat regarding the question. (Actually a special case of the question). I think the answer should be edited so that a viewer can understand that this is not really the correct answer, without reading the comments..

Comment: whole area used by `Component lightweight = new Component() {  - at (java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=142,height=161])` returns getBounds from `JFrame`s `ContentPane`, doesn't matter if is there one, two or three `Components` addded to `JFrame`s `ContentPane` (by using e.g. GridLayout), getClip without custom painting returns ContentPane`s bounds

Comment: @Ramesh-X Yes I know Swing is lightweight. That's not the question. The question is that the Javadoc do not state anywhere that the quoted text would not apply to lightweights. Anyhow as I said my example does not use Swing.

Comment: @mKorbel. No, I'm using AWT lightweights -- directly instanting `Component` and not one of its subclasses. And yes I know that getClip is returning the parent's bounds. But I did not set the clip explicitly, so according to the Javadocs, getClip() should return null.